# Microsoft Azure Active Directory single sign-on for JIRA LDAP directory sync failure

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, single-sign-on, jira, saml

I've set up Jira server on azure kubernetes with Microsoft Azure Active Directory single sign-on for JIRA plugin installed (following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/jiramicrosoft-tutorial).
The application has LDAP directories set up too (using Microsoft Active Directory) which stop working when the plugin is enabled. In the log file I get the following error:

```
com.atlassian.crowd.exception.OperationFailedException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create DirContext instance for transaction;
nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: <gc hostname>:port;
nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: <gc hostname>:port [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
```

Synchronization is failing but I can login to the application using the ldap accounts.
The SSO is causing other issues too. The 'Add Directory' button in the User Directories section is not responding and custom fields are not being displayed.

I found some examples of SSO that require an entry in the seraph-config.xml file, but I couldn't find any reference to the authenticator class used by the Microsoft SSO.

This issue has been blocking our POC progress for quite some time now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your plugin override any LDAP config? seems the config isn't connecting to the LDAP or it's getting blocked.

Comment: @AnnadatePiyush the config only has options related to Azure AD, I don't think there's any that would block LDAP.

Comment: Seems the server.xml changes where done too - here the error indicates for the port mismatch. If you're running this on non-prod; kindly re-check with the ports of application vs config port in server.xml (if changed). Kindly share error details for the other issue being occurred.